# Assign random array values to div's jQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to build css masonry with different sizes in height and width. i have 5 sizes which will be randomly assigned to my `<li>`'s. every next `<li>` will be given a different width generated from the array.

psuedo code:

```
function randomNumber(){
    var textArray = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
    $("ul li").each(function(){
        $(this).html(textArray[randomNumber]);
    });
}


<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

please guide or help

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a random number, use Math.random. The Mozilla docs show an example of getting a random number with a min and max value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but I am going to assume that you need to get a random index from an array of widths.

To do this I created a prototype function on the array object to return a random index from the array.

Then I looped an `[number]` amount of times to dynamically add `li` elements to a specified `ul` as an example. The contents of each `li` here gets filled in with a random number returned from the array.

[jsFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/SidOfc/g2my1hdL/)

The random number function and the setup also use jQuery, as you did in your example as well.

Hope it helps! Good luck

Comment: Thank you Sidney... your feedback really helped